# How can I transform these two "for loops" into "foreach loops" in R in order to get the same kind of result?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, nested-for-loop

I have a code that takes quite a lot of time to run. According to my rough estimates, it would take several days to run it over my set of combinations that I want to test, so I always run it on a smaller set. For that reason I wish I could transform it into foreach loop construct to take advantage of multicore processsor. I have been struggling to convert the following code into foreach loop.

```
pcall=c
lcall=d
pandlcall=c()
pandl=c()
cltime=c()
clpr=c()

for (i in 1:(dim(poss)[1]-1)) {
    for (j in 1:(length(b)-poss[i,2])) {
      if ((b[poss[i,2]+j]-b[poss[i,2]])/b[poss[i,2]]>=pcall) {
        pandlcall[i]=1
        pandl[i]=(b[poss[i,2]+j]-b[poss[i,2]])/b[poss[i,2]]
        cltime[i]=poss[i,2]+j
        clpr[i]=b[poss[i,2]+j]
        break
      } else {
        if ((b[poss[i,2]+j]-b[poss[i,2]])/b[poss[i,2]]<=lcall) {
          pandlcall[i]=-1
          pandl[i]=(b[poss[i,2]+j]-b[poss[i,2]])/b[poss[i,2]]
          cltime[i]=poss[i,2]+j
          clpr[i]=b[poss[i,2]+j]
          break
        } else {
          next
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically I am trying to create a forex backtesting. As you can see, the code above saves specific values when certain criteria of either profit or loss are made. After having run both loops, I would like to have a data.frame of the `pandlcall, pandl, cltime, clpr`, that is why I save this values as vectors during each iteration. `b` and `poss` are another data.frames over which I am running the loops as you can see.

I have been struggling for days to remake it so that it can be used in dopar foreach. During my trials and errors I replaced saving values from vectors into lists, so instead of having e.g. `pandlcall[i]=1` I had `reslist[[1]][i]=1`, so in the end I did not have a data.frame but a list. Before the loops, I created this empty list `reslist=list(pandlcall,pandl,cltime,clprice)`.

For these two basic for loops (i & j) it works, but when I "replace" the outer for loop with foreach loop, it does not work of course. The idea that I had in my mind was like I would create a list which would have these 4 objects ("vectors"), every i-th loop would put a value onto i-th position of each object.

Comment: This what you are looking for?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html

Comment: You might want to look at https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/ (Disclaimer: I'm the author of this tuto/blog post).

Comment: I know that I am looking for dopar foreach. I have already used it several times before. However what I am trying to find is help. Somebody that would have idea how to transfor my current for loop structure into parallel structure in order to be able to obtain the same results I am getting know. As you can see, days have passed and I made no progress.